# JSX can't parse partial HTML tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-rails

I'm using `react-rails` and I need to be able to pass just a start HTML tag (ie: `<form>`) and just an end tag into an array (ie: `</form>`) in my JSX file. When I try doing either or I get a ***ExecJS::RuntimeError*** that says ***SyntaxError: unknown: Unexpected token***.

This doesn't work:

`array.push(<form>)`

This works:

`array.push(<form></form>)`

Comment: I'm not clear on the problem. You need to pass either the start tag, or the close tag but not both?

Comment: Try `array.push(<form/>);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSX is syntactic sugar for creating tags in JavaScript using the React library.

```
<form></form>
```

in JSX compiles to:

```
React.createElement("form", null);
```

([Try it!](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%3Cform%3E%3C%2Fform%3E))

JSX is *not* "HTML as a string" or whatever other way you might be thinking it works. It simply does not work the way you seem to want it to.

Without more detail about what exactly you want to achieve with this, we cannot help you further.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue just now. I wanted to be able to add the separate tags so I can dynamically insert JSX tags or props in the middle. However, I used a work around for this.

You could potentially use functions to get similar functionality you want to insert items in between tags you wanted to split. For example, I wanted to put items in between the tbody and tr tags. I'm using ES6 syntax and Javascript classes here:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
class Table extends Component {

  constructor(props)
    this.powerLevels = 
    [
      {level: "1", comment: "Weakling!"} , 
      {level: "9001", comment: "It's over 9000!"}
    ];
  } 


  //Adds columns in between the rows
  addColumns = (index) => {
    return (
      <td> {this.powerLevels[index].level} </td>
      <td> {this.powerLevels[index].comment} </td>
    }
  }
  //Adds a table row
  addRow = (index) => {
    return (
      <tr>
        {this.addColumns(index)};
      </tr>);
  }

  generateTable = () => {
    let tableLength = this.powerLevels.length;
    let jsxArray = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < tableLength; i++){
      jsxArray.push(this.addRow(i));
    }

    return  (<tbody> {jsxArray} </tbody> );
  }

  render () {

    //{} these brackets allow for Javascript to be written
    return (
      <div>

        {this.generateTable()}

      </div>
    );
  }
}
```